# From flask, how to send the matplotlib plot image into JSON object?

Tags: python, json, image, matplotlib, flask

We are trying to create an API that works with React on the frontend and Flask on the backend. As a part of this, the output that needs to be displayed includes four entities:

2 images (generated using matplotlib)
2 strings.
I have embedded both strings into a JSON object but the images are proving to be difficult.

Is there a way to not store these images and directly embed the generated matplotlib images into the JSON object? Most methods require us to specify the image file name but is there a way to skip saving the files? The sendfile() wouldn't work because we have multiple outputs and our final objective is the JSON response.

Tried creating a temporary file and reading it and this is generating a Buffered Streams ? Base64 would not apply on this I think?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your plot looking the way you'd like, you can **always** base64 encode the file it's stored in and reproduce it on another machine. Take a look:

```
# assume your plot is saved to tfile
with open(tfile) as fin:
    read_in = fin.read()
    b64_data = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(read_in.decode('utf-8'))
# now send over the network
```

Comment: If we don't store the image generated then what would we pass as an argument into the open(), can we just use a variable object? Shouldn't it always be a file name (which we don't have here, in our case).

Comment: You would have to save it to a file, but it could be a tempfile, which is deleted after the run.

Comment: The temp file is sort of giving a bufferedstream which is not readable directly with the f.read() method, we've tried using the io.BufferedReader but it shows an empty stream.

Comment: Yes, the tempfile has a .name parameter returning its name.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3
mpld3 provides a custom stand-alone javascript library built on D3, which parses JSON representations of plots. The mpld3 python module provides a set of routines which parses matplotlib plots (using the mplexporter framework) and outputs the JSON description readable by mpld3.js.