# How can I send a plt/picture (from matplotlib import pyplot as plt) from Flask to render/show/keep in React?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

How can I send a plt/picture (from matplotlib import pyplot as plt) from Flask to render/show/keep in React?

I just took the relevant part from python and react, instead of having all the code here.

main.py

```
plt.savefig("test100.png", transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight', dpi=150) //Here
return send_file('test100.png', mimetype='image/jpg') //Here
```

kmeans.js

```
axios.post(`/kmeans`, {
     cart: this.state.cart
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response) // Here
})
```

I was searching online for example, and I found, but seems to be some depreciated methods that does not work anymore (for example, [how to get an image from flask api in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867734/how-to-get-an-image-from-flask-api-in-react-native#) which results in TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided. at KMeansAlgorithm.js:59) . Not sure I am doing it right in flask as well.

Comment: Generally physical file is not sent back from backend server to frontend. The URL of the file is shared and frontend (React or Angular) directly load it from that URL

Comment: Can you give me an example? If I understand you right, I tried something like: <img src={ require('../../../backend/test100.png') }  alt={''}/> but than react say Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../backend/test100.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: You can send a base64 file like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388276/from-flask-how-to-send-the-matplotlib-plot-image-into-json-object  . I guess what you really are expecting is some way to send all parameters of a plot over a json and some library in javascript converting it into a plot. I am looking for such an option.

Comment: Thanks. I just saved in plt.savefig("../frontend/src/test100.png") and than in react                   <img src={ require('../test100.png') }  alt={''}/>. I hope that if i deploy the website it won't make a problem.